# Put Skype in messaging menu of unity panel?

Tags: unity, skype, messaging-menu

I have Thunderbird and Pidgin that run in the Messaging Menu and are nicely integrated. But running Skype give it its own icon on the Unity Panel. How can I move it into the Messaging Menu? Can these things be "moved" with some reconfiguration?

I'm new to Ubuntu Unity and really like how clean the interface is, but the big green Skype icon kills it.

Comment: The problem there is that Skype is made from a company that does not integrate it into the Messaging Menu. Did you try to contact its developers to ask for this functionality? (But I strongly doubt that they will hear you!)

Answer (score 1):

For versions of Ubuntu *up to Trusy Tahr* you are after `skype-wrapper`. This is available by using the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype-wrapper
```

No package yet for Xenial Xerus unfortunately...

**References:**

- [How to Integrate Skype With Ubuntu Unity](https://www.maketecheasier.com/integrate-skype-with-ubuntu-unity/)
- [Launchpad: "Skypewrapper" team](https://launchpad.net/~skype-wrapper/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)